# Path integral Monte-Carlo simulations of the $t$-$J$ model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software

I'm working on the $t$-$J$ model, i.e, a strong correlation limit and effective low energy theory for the hubbard model. I am interested to simulate a two dimensional square lattice  $t$-$J$ model using Path integral monte carlo, a technique in quantum monte carlo simulation.

I just wanted to know whether there are open sources for path integral monte carlo techniques (any language is fine) which are based on Suzuki-Trotter decomposition.

Comment: Have you searched any of the relevant terms in github for existing open source packages?